# PHP JSON data value all same

Tags: php

I'm on PHP JSON query with database.

```
$qAdzanIqomah = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_sholat WHERE active = 'Y'");
while($dAdzanIqomah = mysqli_fetch_array($qAdzanIqomah))
{
    $sholatName[] = $dAdzanIqomah['sholat_name'];

    $audio_before_adzan[] = $dAdzanIqomah['audio_before_adzan'];

    $iq = $dAdzanIqomah['iqamah'];

    echo $iqamahC[] = date("H:i:s", strtotime("+ '" . $iq . "' minutes"));
}

$data = array(
    'iqamah' => $iqamahC
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

The problem is, all the result is same even on table data is variations.

Result echo `$iqamaC[]`:

```
{"iqamah":["01:00:00","01:00:00","01:00:00","01:00:00","01:00:00"]}
```

-

```
01:00:00
01:00:00
01:00:00
01:00:00
01:00:00
```

Result echo `$iq`:

```
11
12
17
13
10
```

Is there something wrong with that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ***unnecessary quotes and spaces*** in the ***minute-adding code***, and that is the ***actual cause*** of the issue (***failing to add minutes***)

Remove unnecessary quotes like below:-

```
$iqamahC[] = date("H:i:s", strtotime("+$iq minutes"));
```

And check.

A demo working example:-https://eval.in/891471

Comment: @HiDayurieDave  glad to help you :):)